# zsync link error

Tags: konsole, zsync

I've been using zsync for the last few months in order to keep up with the daily lives and recently the link for the zsync file for ubuntu studio has been causing an error in konsole.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with trying to HTTPS the `zsync` file.  Not entirely sure WHY, but `zsync` doesn't handle the `https` protocol nicely.

Pull the `zsync` file down without HTTPS - the `http` link works fine.

Comment: Proceeded with the above recommendation and was successful. Thank you.

Comment: @JediBuddha glad to hear it!  Please feel free to mark this question as accepted with the checkmark on the left side of the answer in order to mark this question as solved :)